# CheckBox Angular 4 ngfor problema al selecionar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Estoy diseñando un Modal con boostrap y dentro de el tengo una lista de checkBox que se carga recorriendo un NGFOR.

El problema es el siguiente:
A la hora de seleccionar uno de esos elementos  se seleccionan todos los checkbox, ademas no tengo muy claro como recibir en informacion de los checkbox selecciones en el component.ts

Como puedo hacer para seleccionar solo los valores que quiera? y ademas enviar la información a mi componente?

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-6" *ngFor="let data of sensor">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="data.name" name= "miDataInterior" [(ngModel)]="miDataInterior">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">{{data.name}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: Img CheckBox]

EDIT01

Hola,

la información que estoy pintando en el ngfor es la siguiente:

```
["var_TempExt","var_HumRExt","var_HumRInt","var_Humedad_Sust1","var_Humedad_Sust2","var_PotActInv","var_PotActBio","var_ContadorRiego","var_RadiacionGlobalInt","var_RadiacionPARInt","var_CO2InvVaisala","var_TempInt","var_RadiacionExt","var_CO2Exterior","var_VVExt","var_DVExt","var_Lluvia","act_AbrirVentanaCen","act_AbrirVentanaLatNS","act_Aerotermo","act_BombaCalefaccion","act_Deshumificacion","act_Humidification","act_LuzArtificial","act_ValvulaTresVias"]
```

Necesito poder seleccionar cualquiera de esos nombres y enviar ese nombre en un array a mi componente para luego pasarlos al servicio.

En el ts tengo un método simple para mostrarme la información que tiene el modal, pero solo recupero un true

```
public guardar(){
      console.log('formulario posteado: ' + this.checkbox);
    }
```

Comment: coloca el archivo typescript o mas precisamente la lista sensor para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar el Post por si queda mas claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi idea para resolver los problemas:

Crear en el componente una estructura con los campos de los checkboxes:

```
//asumo que sensor es el array ["var_TempExt", "var_HumRExt", "var_HumRInt", ... ]
checkboxes= {};
sensor.forEach(nombre => checkboxes[nombre]=false);
```

Con lo que tendrías un objeto con atributos llamados igual que cada checkbox inicializados a false.

Y luego haces algo como:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-6" *ngFor="let data of sensor; let i= index">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name= "miDataInterior" 
        [(ngModel)]="checkboxes[data.name]" id="{{'inlineCheckbox' + i}}">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{'inlineCheckbox' + i}}">{{data.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, antes de nada gracias por la ayuda. He probado añadiendo los corchetes y sigue pasando lo mismo :S

Comment: los valores que yo pinto son los siguientes y no veo problema: sensores completos: ["var_TempExt","var_HumRExt","var_HumRInt","var_Humedad_Sust1","var_Humedad_Sust2","var_PotActInv","var_PotActBio","var_ContadorRiego","var_RadiacionGlobalInt","var_RadiacionPARInt","var_CO2InvVaisala","var_TempInt","var_RadiacionExt","var_CO2Exterior","var_VVExt","var_DVExt","var_Lluvia","act_AbrirVentanaCen","act_AbrirVentanaLatNS","act_Aerotermo","act_BombaCalefaccion","act_Deshumificacion","act_Humidification","act_LuzArtificial","act_ValvulaTresVias"]

Comment: lo curioso es que si elimino el [(ngModel)]="miDataInterior" si puedo seleccionar uno por uno los nombres, pero no se como enviarlos al componente

Comment: Quita la etiqueta id y debería funcionar

Comment: @JackNavaRow Bien visto! No sé cómo no me he dado cuenta

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, este es mi código en estos momentos: <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-6" *ngFor="let data of sensor">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                  [value]="data.name" name= "miDataInterior" [(ngModel)]="miDataInterior">
                                  <label class="form-check-label">{{data.name}}</label>
                                </div>
                              </div>

Comment: Sensores es un array de strings?

Comment: Si, sensores es un array de string con un unico campo el nombre del sensor

Comment: Tengo dos campos uno con respuesta completa que si tiene el campo .name que es sensor y otro que es sensores que es solo un array sin el name. Da igual el que use que siguen marcandose todos los check. he probado tando con sensor  con el .name como el sensores sin el y nada. :(

Comment: mi problema esta cuando uso el NGMODEL, si lo elimino si puedo seleccionar uno a uno y no entiendo esto

Comment: Creo que he encontrado la solución....

Comment: Hola, parece que la cosa mejora pero no termina de ir del todo bien. Ahora cuando selecciono uno de ellos me cambia el label a false o true :S, ¿es mas facil hacer esto con radiobuton?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80657/discussion-between-pablo-lozano-and-manolait).

Comment: Hola, una duda siempre me esta mostrando el siguiente campo NAME y no tendría que aparecer no? {"name":"false","var_TempInt":true}

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR: Estas enlazando `miDataInterior` a **todos** los checkbox

Para resolverlo hay una infinidad de soluciones posibles. Lo que tienes que entender es que cuando haces `[(ngModel)]="miDataInterior"` en cada checkbox, estas enlazando esa variable a todos ellos. Si `miDataInterior` cambia, lo haran todos ellos.

Una solución sencilla es no usar el enlace, sino los eventos del DOM. Cuando un usuario cambie el valor del checkbox, agregar o quitar ese elemento a un arreglo que será el resultado. Esto se logra con el evento `(change)` y revisar si el `target.checked` del evento está activo:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
  name= "miDataInterior" (change)="$event.target.checked ? agregar(data) : quitar(data)">
```

Y en el componente:

```
  agregar(data: string) { // Agregamos el elemento
    this.miDataInterior.push(data);
  }

  quitar(data) { // Filtramos el elemento para que quede fuera
    this.miDataInterior = this.miDataInterior.filter(s => s !== data);
  }
```

De esta manera podés usar arreglos de strings o de cualquier tipo de datos. Podés encontrar la solución funcionando en [este Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syoypb). Allí podés ver que también funciona con arreglos de objetos.

Seguro podés encontrar otras soluciones, pero debés entender que cada `checkbox` tiene que tener su variable por separado.